# Is it possible to conditionally execute a statement if there is no exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

Consider the following function. I have written it in C#.

```
public void Test()
{
    statement1;
    try
    {
        statement2;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //Exception caught
    }
}
```

I want to execute `statement1` only if `statement2` causes no exception. Is it possible to execute `statement1` only when `statement2`  doesn't throw any exception?

Comment: By moving `statement1;` under `statement2;`?

Comment: I want to execute statement1 first if there is no exception. I wants to maintain the sequential order as it is.

Comment: I wants to add import a blank pdf and then needs to add existing fields on it. If addition of fields causes exception, I don't want to import the pdf as well.

Comment: You want a time machine?

Comment: Sorry I am new to C#. I need to manually delete the pdf if exception caught. I am searching for an alternative if there is any.

Comment: What is stopping you from doing so? S.Akbari's answer is correct from the problem you've described in your question.

Comment: @John: It's not, because the asker clearly wants statement1 to execute first (as impossible as that is).

Comment: @BoltClock Then as Damien suggested, OP wants a time machine. We could probably offer something better than that if more code was provided, of course :-)

Comment: You can set the timer or await for that.But,it's not good way so faar.

Comment: @John: Yeah pretty much the entire thing needs to be rewritten because the use case they just described, really doesn't require time travel...

Comment: Manually deleting the blank pdf will took a small delay. But I understood, that is the only solution. Thanks for your guidelines.

Comment: @Prasanth: How much of a delay can deleting a blank PDF take, unless you're storing it in the filesystem as soon as it's created (which you probably shouldn't be doing)?

Comment: @BoltClock There are some milliseconds only. I afraid that it was not a good coding practice to add a blank pdf and just delete it if an exception occurs.

Comment: @Prasanth: Don't worry about that. If you need a PDF to work with before you can determine if adding those fields would be successful, then just make the PDF temporarily. You probably won't even notice those milliseconds.

Comment: @BoltClock Okay. Thanks for the expert advice.

Comment: @Prasanth So, would you like to accept one of the following answer ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can easily do it in this way

```
public void Test()
{
    try
    {
        statement2;
        statement1;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //Exception caught
    }
}
```

statement1 will not run if statement2 throws some exceptions.

Another way, not so cool, would be to use a variable

```
public void Test()
    {
        bool completed=false;
        try
        {
            statement2;
            completed=true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Exception caught
        }
        if (completed)
          statement1;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the order and logic of statements. You cannot foresee an exception during runtime

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood your question correctly, this is what you want (moving `statement1;` under `statement2;`):

```
try
{
    statement2;
    statement1;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //Exception caught
}
```

By using this way, the `statement1` will be executed only if `statement2` causes no exception!

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, all you have to do is to move statement 1 under statement 2, since the compiler will reach statement1 only if statement 2 did not throw any exception. Code below:

```
 public void Test()
{
try
{
    statement2;
    statement1;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //Exception caught
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can recall the method after the exception ,

```
public void Test(bool noerror= false)
{
   if (noerror)
      statement1;

    try
    {
        statement2;
        completed=true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         noerror=true;
        Test(noerror)
        //Exception caught
    }

}
```

Comment: Wait what? What makes you believe that re-running the same code if an exception occurs will work at some point? Also where does `completed` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is and you are actually using it (but wrong).

`try...catch` block is meant to catch exceptions and take apropriate actions whether exception was thrown or not:

```
try
{
    // risky operation that might throw exception
    RiskyOperation();
    // here code is executed when no exception is thrown
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // code here gets executed when exception is thrown
}
finally
{
    // this code evaluates independently of exception occuring or not
}
```

To sum up, you need to do:

```
try
{
    statement2;
    statement1;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // code here gets executed when exception is thrown
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can opt to recursion, but we need to make sure it doesn't end up as infinity loop.

```
public void Test()
{
   bool hasException = false;
   statement1;
   try
   {
       statement2;
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
       hasException = true;
   }
   finally
   {
       if(hasException)
           Test();
   }
}
```

Comment: Wait what? What makes you believe that re-running the same code if an exception occurs will work at some point?

Comment: :) well, depending upon the functional context, it is the programmer's duty to make sure at some threshold point program must exit.

Comment: Yeah, but as is, your code will very likely either run fine the first time, or end up in an infinite loop. I mean if `statement2` throws an exception the first time, it will likely throw it too the second time and every time after that. ("*Insanity: doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results.*")

Comment: There are many ways to exit from this, for example  you can have a global variable say var RetryCount = 5; , increment this var on each recursive call and exit when it reaches 6. It all depends on the requirement and context.