# C# Execute code only if other code was successful

Tags: c#, error-handling

Say I have

```
Method1(); // might return error
Method2(); // should only be executed if previous line successful
```

I could use `try` and `catch`, however I still want errors to **happen**, I just don't want `Method2()` to be run if any errors occurred.

Comment: why not mak `Method1` returning a bool indicating its sucess?

Comment: How do you know an error happened? Is an exception thrown or is there an error code returned?

Comment: If `Method1` throws an exception, then the code will never proceed to the next statement to call `Method2`, so it will never get called...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288496/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-execute-a-statement-if-there-is-no-exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "template" for functions that looks like this:

```
bool TrySomething( out int returnValue )
```

which return true if successful and false if not. The `returnValue` is only valid if the returned bool is true. So you can use those like this:

```
if( TrySomething(out int someValue) )
{
     Method2( someValue );
}
```

The various `TryParse` methods of different types are examples of that.

---

Another approach would be if `Method1` throws an exception:

```
Method1();
// If Method1 throws an exception, Method2 will not be executed.
// The control flow will be redirected to the "next" catch block
// that handles the exception type or if none of those exist crash 
// the app.
Method2();
```

So, even if you do not surround this with a try/catch block and `Method1` throws, the control flow *will not* move on to execute `Method2`.

If you *do* use a try/catch block, `Method2` will also *not* be executed:

```
try
{
    Method1(); // throws 
    Method2(); // won't execute
}
catch(SomeException ex)
{
    // Control flow will continue here.
    // Handle that exception
}
finally // optional
{
    // This will be executed regardless of whether there was an exception or not.
}
```

---

For further reading:

- [Exceptions and Exception Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/)

Comment: It might be worth noting that the try/catch block isn't what prevents `Method2` from being called. It seems that this is what OP is confused about.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @ProgrammingLlama you should do something like this:

```
     try {
        MethodWithErrorOrException();
        MethodAfter();
     }
     catch (Exception) {
        // Handling
     }
     finally {
        MethodAlwaysCalled();
     }
```

Naturally MethodWithErrorOrException() should rise Exception.

Alternatively you have to use a return value to the method MethodWithErrorOrException() to understand if everything was successful, but it is not the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make Method1 return false on error.
Than you can use it like this:

`if(Method1()){Method2();}`

Comment: Your answer is similar to the accepted answer but less complete because it miss the return error code.